# How to get StyleRules as a string output using ExCSS Parser

Tags: c#, asp.net, parsing, html-parsing, css-parsing

I'm using [ExCSS](https://github.com/TylerBrinks/ExCSS) to parse and manipulate a stylesheet string. So far so good.

But I can't find any documentation on how to convert the manipulated style rules into a string.

Although the code may not be relevant to this question, this is what I'm doing:

```
private string ManipulateCSS(string styles)
{
    ExCSS.Parser parser = new ExCSS.Parser();
    var stylesheet = parser.Parse(styles);

    // here I perform specific manipulations 
    // which are not relevant to this question...
    stylesheet.StyleRules
                  .SelectMany(r => r.Declarations)
                  .Where(d => d.Name == "<something>"
                  ...

    ...

    // Now, the next line is where I'm having issues: 
    // how to return the whole string with styles out of this ExCSS parser?
    return stylesheet.StyleRules.ToString();
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the `ToString()` method needs to be called on the ExCSS.StyleSheet instance and I was calling it on the StyleRules collection.

You only need to do the following (as per my sample code in the question above):

```
return stylesheet.ToString();
```

I hope this answer might save someone else's time.